# SQL Query with Order by Strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

```
dim Symbol_Val as string
```

I put my preference in entering the stocks according to my order in symbol_val

For example

```
Symbol val="stock1,stock2,stock3,stock4,stock5,stock6,stock7,stock8,stock9"
```

Then I execute the query

```
"Select Symbol, trade_date , sec_close,volume from stockPrice WHERE symbol in (" & Symbol_Val & ") and NO_OF_RECORDS= (SELECT max(no_of_records) FROM stockPrice_Alert) ORDER BY" & Symbol_Val
```

When I execute the query I am not getting the records as per my preference
can anyone tell me what the query is required to be execute in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `charindex()` to find the value.  A simplistic method is:

```
Select Symbol, trade_date, sec_close, volume
from stockPrice
where symbol in (" & Symbol_Val & ") and NO_OF_RECORDS = (SELECT max(no_of_records) FROM stockPrice_Alert)
order by charindex(Symbol_Val, val)
```

It is better to take the delimiters into account:

```
order by charindex(','+Symbol_Val+',', ','+val+',')
```

Comment: This charindex function is not recognized by sql 6